# i am trying to upload file with arabic name in django upload file

Tags: python, django, unicode

i am trying to make upload file button upload file in Arabic named
with `form = UploadFileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`
but when i select Arabic named file it does not add it without giving any error
my views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        
            form = UploadFileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
            
            if form.is_valid():
             portfolio=form.save(commit=False)
             portfolio.user = request.user 
             portfolio.file= form.filename.decode('utf8')
             portfolio.save()
            return redirect('upload_file')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
            files = UploadedBooksFile.objects.all()
            
            return render(request, 'upload_file.html', {'form': form, 'files': files})

def download_file(request, file_id):
    uploaded_file = UploadedBooksFile.objects.get(pk=file_id)
    response = HttpResponse(uploaded_file.file, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{uploaded_file.file.name}"'
    return response
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error (i removed the portfolio.file= form.filename.decode('utf8') line becuase it was not correct) but after i select the file to upload nothing is uploaded but only english files only uploaded)

Comment: Could you add the html of the form? Where are you storing the uploaded files?

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div>
            <table id="customers" style="float:right;width:80%;padding-right:3rem;">

        <tr><td><h2>اضغط على المفتاح التالى لرفع الملف  الى الخادم</h2></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="savebutton" style="border-radius:5px;width:10rem;heiSght:3rem;">رفع</button></td></tr>

        
        
        </div>
    </table>
    </form>

Comment: Please update your question with this html (and remove the portfolio.file= form.filename.decode('utf8') line as well)